# Tensorflow won't import in Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm new to ML and Colab. Trying to play around with the project at https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans but having a hard time getting it running in Colab.

When I run the import_example.py script from the project, I get immediate errors relating to Tensorflow not loading. So I tried stepping back and simply doing `import tensorflow as tf`. When I run this, I get the below errors. I've got the runtime set to GPU. I was getting the same issue yesterday with the Colab demo GPU code, but that's working today.

Can anyone give me any pointers? It seems like basic stuff that should just work in the environment.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing the same issue. Later I realized I forgot to enable **GPU** in notebook settings.

I enabled it and installed **TensorFlow-GPU** (GPU version).

You can find notebook settings in **Edit** > **Notebook Settings**.

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr7Hr.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have installed the version of tensorflow that you need in Colab or not?! (Maybe you have installed a different version of tensorflow-gpu and you have not installed the corresponding tensorflow version. I got the same error in this case)

```
!pip list
```

If you do not have tensorflow in the list, you should install both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu as follow:

```
!pip install tensorflow=='enter version here'
!pip install tensorflow-gpu=='enter same version as the previous one here'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to read the error carefully:

> NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
>   manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

Try running:

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

inside notebook, and then rerun the cell with the import.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is included by default in Colab. So, I suspect you've somehow broken the existing install.

You can request a new backend by selecting the Runtime -> Reset all runtimes... menu. Then, try `import tensorflow as tf` again.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - it was a CUDA version issue. Colab was on 9.2 and it looked as if Tensorflow was expecting 9.0. I followed the instructions at https://medium.com/@nickzamosenchuk/training-the-model-for-ios-coreml-in-google-colab-60-times-faster-6b3d1669fc46 , dropping from 9.2 to 9.0 instead of 9.2 to 9.0 like the author was doing and then it worked.